# How to throw an error using try catch statement?

Tags: javascript

```
//Utility
  const readUserUtility = (id_a)=>{
    const currentstore = store.getState();
    const returnedArray = currentstore.users.filter((user_object)=>{
        return user_object.id === id_a;
    })

    try{if(returnedArray.length === 0){throw "Array empty";}}catch(error){
    console.log(error);


    }

    console.log(returnedArray);
  }
```

I have this function readUserUtility as part of a redux application. When i call readuserUtility with an integer im getting the error:
  Line 144:  Expected an object to be thrown  no-throw-literal

The message "Array empty" still shows up in the console, but why am i getting this error?

Comment: It’s a [linter warning](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-throw-literal) which is explained at its documentation. Use `throw new Error("Array empty");`.

Comment: "Error" or "warning"? Because they *are different things* - https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-throw-literal tldr; *Search first* next time.

Comment: Also if you want to be able to throw literals, then disable this rule.

Comment: Thanks, ive only been learning javascript for around 1 week

Comment: @MichaelLee Have you searched the message _“Expected an object to be thrown no-throw-literal”_? The linked article appears as the first result in Google. Research is part of learning anything and is almost always much faster than asking a question (especially when you’re presented with a Googleable warning or error message).

Comment: No, but its easier to ask people. If its a rule, then i will follow from now on

Comment: In any case, no matter which language, or even outside software engineering, make yourself familiar with the tool before you use. If you use eslint your code project, then you should make yourself familiar with it first. If you don't know the meaning of the messages that the tool is providing to you, then it fails to fulfill its purpose.

Comment: @MichaelLee Recommended reading:  [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  A lot.  Please do research first in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new Error object and pass that. Below works for me:

`throw new Error("item not found");`